# HQL version of a SQL join with group by

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, group-by, hql

I have two tables, Band and Votes.  Band has a name and an id, and Votes has a total_votes column and a foreign key called band_id pointing to band.id.

I have lots of votes, saved at various dates.  What I want to do is find the maximum value of the total_votes column for each band.  The following SQL query works:

```
select b.name,max(v.total_votes) as total from band b, votes v 
    where b.id=v.band_id
    group by b.name order by total desc;
```

The system I'm working with, though, uses Hibernate.  I'd like to re-write that SQL query as either HQL or a Hibernate criteria query.

Is this easy and I'm just missing it?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In HQL, could you give this a try:

```
select band.name, max(vote.totalVotes)
from Band band
     join band.votes vote
group by band.name
order by max(vote.totalVotes) desc
```

This assumes there is a one-to-many association between `Band` and `Votes` (actually, providing the object model is very helpful when working with HQL and/or the Criteria API since you are querying the object model).

Just in case, here is the relevant section of the documentation:

> #### [14.12. The group by clause](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-grouping)
>
> A query that returns aggregate values
>   can be grouped by any property of a
>   returned class or components:
>
> ```
> select cat.color, sum(cat.weight), count(cat)
> from Cat cat
> group by cat.color
>
> select foo.id, avg(name), max(name)
> from Foo foo join foo.names name
> group by foo.id
> ```
>
> A having clause is also allowed.
>
> ```
> select cat.color, sum(cat.weight), count(cat)
> from Cat cat
> group by cat.color
> having cat.color in (eg.Color.TABBY, eg.Color.BLACK)
> ```
>
> SQL functions and aggregate functions
>   are allowed in the having and order by
>   clauses if they are supported by the
>   underlying database (i.e., not in
>   MySQL).
>
> ```
> select cat
> from Cat cat
>     join cat.kittens kitten
> group by cat.id, cat.name, cat.other, cat.properties
> having avg(kitten.weight) > 100
> order by count(kitten) asc, sum(kitten.weight) desc
> ```
>
> Neither the group by clause nor the
>   order by clause can contain arithmetic
>   expressions. Hibernate also does not
>   currently expand a grouped entity, so
>   you cannot write group by cat if all
>   properties of cat are non-aggregated.
>   You have to list all non-aggregated
>   properties explicitly.