# Create HQL from SQL with group by clause

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, group-by, hql

I would like to translate this SQL into HQL :

```
select t1.id , COUNT(*) as number
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id = 2 OR t2.id = 3
GROUP BY t1.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Could anyone help me on this please?

PS : I found this solution which is working for me 
SQL :

```
select t1.id 
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
inner join Table2 t3 on t1.id = t3.id
WHERE t2.id = 2
and t3.id = 3
```

HQL :

```
select t1 from Table1 t1
inner join t1.fonctionalObject t2 
inner join t1.fonctionalObject t3 
where t2.id = 2 
and t3.id = 3
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [HQL version of a SQL join with group by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402583/hql-version-of-a-sql-join-with-group-by)

Comment: Of course you can do this by `HQL` as @Dragondraikk answer.But `Hibernate Criteria` is the best in my opinion

Comment: What about this query doesn't work in HQL?

Comment: Note that if you found the answer yourself, you can also provide it as an answer here on Stack Overflow

Comment: what's the best practise ? Should i add the answer in a new comment or edit my original post ?