# HQL query ORDER BY not working

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I'm using Spring Data JPA alongside Hibernate's HQL to create database queries.

So essentially, I have two tables. One table has user data, another has "campaigns" that the businesses have uploaded. These campaigns have views. I want to sum the views, group by business id, then order by the views.

The query works as in it pulls the proper data from the database, it sums the views, but it does not order them. I've been trying every which way to fix the order but can't seem to find a solution.

My Spring Data JPA method with the query above it:

```
@Query("SELECT b, SUM(c.currentViews) AS views FROM BusinessUser b LEFT JOIN b.businessData.campaigns AS c"
                + " WHERE b.businessName LIKE %:keyword% GROUP BY c.businessUser ORDER BY views")
        public List<Object[]> lookupBusinessesByKeyword(@Param("keyword") String keyword);
```

Query formatted a bit nicer:

```
SELECT
  *,
  SUM(c.currentViews) AS views
FROM BusinessUser b
  LEFT JOIN b.businessData.campaigns AS c
WHERE b.businessName LIKE % :keyword %
GROUP BY c.businessUser
ORDER BY views
```

Example of what I want:

```
business_users table 
-----------------------
id    name
1     businessOne
2     businessTwo
3     businessThree

campaigns table
-----------------------
id   business_id    title     views
1      1            title     200
2      1            title     200
3      2            title     300
4      2            title     400
5      3            title     100


joined table
-----------------------
businessId     name         SUM(views)
3              businessOne    700
1              businessTwo    400
2              businessThree  100
```

Right now, the query works but does not order the views in the right order. The table is ordered by `businessId` instead of the sum of the views and I'm not sure how to fix it.

**EDIT**
My current results:

```
businessId     name         SUM(views)
1              businessTwo    400
2              businessThree  100
3              businessOne    700
```

Comment: seems to be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402583/hql-version-of-a-sql-join-with-group-by

Comment: @JohnDonn I just tried that and it's still not ordered properly :/. Any idea what could be wrong with my query? Is it what I'm grouping by?

Comment: @JohnDonn I removed the `GROUP BY` portion of the query and the output is the same. So I think my `GROUP BY` is wrong. But I've tried 5 different things for `GROUP BY` and it still won't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: This might be obvious, but in your place I would try to debug the SQL generated by the JPQL query (if needed, running it explicitly, without the @ Query annotation), then trying different variants, and changing the query each time slightly until it works. "b.businessData.campaigns" looks to me a bit suspicious, but I don't know what are your entities (I would expect something like "left join b.businessData bd left join bd.campaigns c"), but I don't remember the syntax peculiarities by heart.

Comment: @JohnDonn `businessData` is an embedded entity containing more fields for the `BusinessUser` entity. And I'll try that. I'm thinking about trying to get a proper SQL query working and then convert that into HQL. Maybe I'm simply overlooking something? I appreciate your response.